# How to save array of int type in database using ajax call in .net mvc?

Tags: arrays, asp.net-mvc, loops, controller, code-first

I need to save my tags in the database using their ids. I will get the tags id in arrays using ajax but don't know how to code the controller so my tags are saved in the table.
I would need to know about the code that I use to save that array in my database.

```
public ActionResult Skills( string[] skills 
                 {
                     using (SkillContext dbskill = new SkillContext())
                     {
                         foreach (var skill in skills)
                         {
                             Skill Skilltag = new Skill();
                             Skilltag.std_skill_id = skills;
                             dbskill.Skill.Add(Skilltag);
                             if (dbskill.SaveChanges() > 0)
                             {
                                 return View();
                             }
                         }
                     }
                     return View();
         
                 }
         
            $(function () {
                     $.validator.setDefaults({
                         submitHandler: function (form, e) {
                             e.preventDefault();
                             
                             var skillsdata = { skills: $("#std_skill_id").val() }
                             
                             console.log(skillsdata);
                             $.ajax({
                                 async: true,
                                 type: 'POST',
                                 url: "/Dashboard/Skills",
         
                                 data:skillsdata,
                                 success: function (data) {
                                     console.log(skillsdata)
                                 }
                             })
                         }
                     });
     
     public class SkillContext : DbContext
         {
             public SkillContext() : base("IntershipPlacement")
             {
             }
             public DbSet<Skill> Skill { get; set; }
             public DbSet<SkillCategory> SkillCategory { get; set; }
     
             public DbSet<Department> Department { get; set; }
             protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
             {
                 modelBuilder.Entity<Skill>().MapToStoredProcedures();
                 modelBuilder.Entity<SkillCategory>().MapToStoredProcedures();
                 modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().MapToStoredProcedures();
             }
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

let's say you want to send this array ['1','2','3']

```
$(function () {
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        submitHandler: function (form, e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            
            var skillsdata = ['1','2','3'];               //******
            
            console.log(skillsdata);
            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/Dashboard/Skills",
                contentType: 'application/json',          //******
                data:JSON.stringfy({skills : skillsdata}),//******
                success: function (data) {
                    // depending on your controller this data object 
                    // will return html and that's wrong,
                    // you need to pass value like (int or string) so you can easely read.
                    console.log(skillsdata)
                }
           });
      }
});
```

in the controller you can return

```
if (dbskill.SaveChanges() > 0)
{
     return Content("1");  // success
}
else
{
     return Content("0");  //  something wrong
}
```